# Problem with jQuery click

Tags: jquery, click

I have a little problem with my click event.

I have an AJAX function that retrieves a JSON object. It works great and my pictures appear as I want.

My problem is that every picture that appears to have a click function in which I will call a function. But it does not work.

Here is what my code looks like:

```
    $.getJSON('url-to-my.fle.php', function( obj ){

    for( var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++ ){

        var value = obj[ i ];
        FOO.bar.app.img.prototype.renderThumbs( myWindow, value['fileName'], value['width'], value['height'] );
    }
});
```

The code above works, my funktion renderThumbs

```
FOO.bar.app.img.prototype.renderThumbs = function( myWindow, imgURL, imgWidth, imgHeight){
    var images = "";

    images = '<div class="imgBox"><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/'+ imgURL +'" alt="" /></a></div>';

    $('.content', myWindow).append(images).hide().fadeIn(800);
    var that = this;

    console.log($(images).find('img'));
    var img = $(images).find('img');

    $(img).live('click', function() {
        console.log('click');
        that.getImg(imgURL, imgWidth, imgHeight);
    });
};
```

I am getting no errors in firebug, nothing happens when I click on the images. I tested with. click (); .bind () and as you can see in my code also .live() and it is the same result with all eventshandlers.

Some tips on how I solve this?

I can not send an ID number in my img tag, then it becomes wrong when I have two galleries running.

Comment: It looks to me that `click` should work.

Comment: AFAIK(I may be wrong!) the code should work, can you try posting a the code somewhere like in http://jsfiddle.net/  so that we can try..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your error is that `images` is a string, not the actual image elements you inserted into the DOM.  Simplified code:

```
images = '<div><img /></div>';
$('.content').append(images);   
var img = $(images).find('img');
```

Basically, you're creating the DOM elements twice: once in `append` and once in the jquery selector where you call `find`.  Changing it to this should work:

```
images = $('<div class="imgBox"><a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/'+ imgURL +'" alt="" /></a></div>';);
```

Because now you are creating the DOM elements only once.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing work on the jQuery object that is created from the string images, not on the DOM object appended under the div with class `content`.  Try:

```
// use last-child to get latest added div
console.log($(".content:last-child").find('img')); 
var img = $(".content:last-child").find('img');
```

Also note that when using `live` you only have to set it up once, perhaps towards the start of your ready.  You can use the selector `.content img` to get all img tags in the .content div.  If content contains other images you don't want to hvae that click act on, try `.imgBox img` perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

If you change this part:

```
 $(img).live('click', function() {        
      console.log('click');
     $(this).getImg(imgURL, imgWidth, imgHeight);
 });
```

and make it be (outside your function):

```
 $('img','.imgBox').live('click', function() {        
      console.log('click');
    $(this).getImg(imgURL, imgWidth, imgHeight);
 });
```

OR use delegate and put it OUTSIDE your function

```
 $('.imgBox').delegate('img','click', function() {        
      console.log('click');
     $(this).getImg(imgURL, imgWidth, imgHeight);
 });
```

to capture the img element directly?

Comment: not sure what your "getImg()" is about, but you can work that part out.